HLTV/results scraper not working. Multiple samed named divs
I am building a script to scrape the hltv.org/results page for cs2 matches. However, I am encountering a lot of issues with this, specifically, the website hltv.org/results?offset={} has multiple divs called results-sublist where the results are stored inside in divs called result-con. My script only scrapes the first results-sublist and is unable to scrape any further, resulting in a lot of missing matches.
My function is defiend as
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen  # Import Request and urlopen
import bs4
import time
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import random

# Base URL for HLTV results with pagination
base_url = 'https://www.hltv.org/results?offset={}'

def scrape_match_links(base_url, num_pages):
    """
    Scrapes match links from the HLTV results pages.

    Parameters:
    base_url (str): The base URL for the HLTV results page.
    num_pages (int): The number of pages to scrape (should be 100 res pr. page).

    Returns:
    list: A list of match links.
    """
    offset = 0
    match_links = []
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    while offset <= num_pages * 100:
        url = base_url.format(offset)
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
        
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
                webpage = response.read().decode('utf-8')
                soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
                
                # Find all results-sublist divs
                results_sublists = soup.find_all('div', class_='results-sublist')
                if not results_sublists:
                    print("No results-sublist found on this page.")
                    break  # Stop if no results are found on this page

                for sublist in results_sublists:
                    results = sublist.find_all('div', class_='result-con')
                    for result in results:
                        match_link = result.find('a')
                        if match_link:
                            full_link = 'https://www.hltv.org' + match_link['href']
                            match_links.append(full_link)  # Append full URL

            offset += 100
            
        except HTTPError as e:
            print(f'HTTPError: {e.code} - {e.reason}')
            break  # Stop if there's an HTTP error (e.g., too many requests)
        except URLError as e:
            print(f'URLError: {e.reason}')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Unexpected error: {str(e)}')
            break

    return match_links

Any insight into why I might be encountering this and/or idea to work around this is greatly appreciated.
Best, Jonas
I have tried to use selenium, it worked on the first page yielding 6 divs of class results-sublist, however, on subsequent pages it returned 0 instances of results-sublist.

I'm going to guess it's because you're using urllib.request, which cannot process javascript.

Hi your target site seems protected by Cloudflare so to run this script you have to bypass the bot detection mechanism by adding user-agent, cookie value in your requests, here is the sample to code that fetch your desired output:
Code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    #your cookie and user-agent header is here
}
for i in range(100, 1000, 100):
    url = f"https://www.hltv.org/results?offset={i}"
    session = requests.Session()
    resp = session.get(url, headers=header).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')
    for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if 'matches/' in i['href']:
            print(f"https://www.hltv.org{i['href']}")

Output:
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376628/tsm-impact-vs-fluffy-mafia-esl-impact-league-season-6-north-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376630/blue-otter-karma-vs-nouns-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-north-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376629/flyquest-red-vs-aware-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-north-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376631/lotus-fe-vs-imp-pact-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-north-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376796/bestia-vs-red-canids-esl-challenger-league-season-48-south-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376624/fluxo-demons-vs-furia-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-south-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376626/atrix-vs-thekillaz-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-south-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376625/mibr-fe-vs-insanity-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-south-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376627/capivaras-vs-peak-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-south-america
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376615/big-equipa-vs-hsg-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376754/3dmax-vs-saw-esl-challenger-league-season-48-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376617/let-her-cook-vs-nip-impact-esl-impact-league-season-6-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376616/dream-catchers-fe-vs-permitta-w-esl-impact-league-season-6-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376619/spirit-fe-vs-ence-athena-esl-impact-league-season-6-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376618/navi-javelins-vs-astralis-w-esl-impact-league-season-6-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376614/imperial-fe-vs-crescent-fe-esl-impact-league-season-6-europe
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376739/ence-vs-9z-elisa-masters-espoo-2024
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376814/unpaid-vs-parivision-res-regional-champions-2024
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376725/aurora-young-blud-vs-cph-wolves-winline-insight-season-6
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376738/b8-vs-jano-elisa-masters-espoo-2024
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2376766/bromo-vs-ihc-esl-challenger-league-season-48-asia-pacific

let me know if this is work on your end
